# Cannot ping from client to internet via IPv6 tunnel

Tags: routing, ipv6, mikrotik

I'm facing an odd issue with my IPv6 setup. I've configured it as follows:

```
/interface 6to4
  add comment="SixXS 6to4 tunnel" local-address=zz.yy.xx.94 (my wan ip) mtu=1280 name=6to4-sixxs remote-address=zz.yy.xx.73 (tunnel endpoint)

/ipv6 address
  add address=2001:aaaa:bbbb:123::2/128 (my ipv6) advertise=no interface=6to4-sixxs
  add address=2001:bbbb:cccc:123::1/64 (subnet for my ipv6 prefix) advertise=yes interface=bridge-lan

/ipv6 route
  add distance=1 dst-address=2000::/3 gateway=6to4-sixxs
```

Now:

- I can ping servers from the router (f.e. 2a00:1450:400c:c03::5e)
- Clients obtain an IPv6 via ND in the correct subnet
- Pings from the router to a client fails (timeout, ping is not dropped by firewall)
- Pings from a client to servers fail

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does the client have a listing in the router's ARP table?  Is there a WAN accelerator anywhere in between the server and the client?

Comment: @Colyn1337: Yes, there is. (address=fe80::60c:ceff:abcd:abcd interface=bridge-lan mac-address=04:0C:CE:xx:xx:xx status="stale"). No WAN accelerator active.

Comment: Any firewalling going on?

Comment: @MichelZ: I've added 3 rules which should allow all traffic (just for testing): input -> accept, forward -> accept, output -> accept

Comment: I'm concerned that the ARP entry is "stale".  The router hasn't been able to verify the address.  Is the firewall between the client and router, or router and server?

Comment: @Colyn1337: the firewall is the built-in firewall on the router. No other firewall is active. I see packets being captured (and accepted) by the rules I've created when I start pinging, but I'm not able to receive a response on my ping on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just came across [this thread on the Mikrotik Forums](http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=57781), and it mentions things about routing caches being stuck. I've decided the reboot the router and it fixed my issue.

Weird stuff. Thanks for thinking along, @Colyn1337 and @MichelZ.